# Font Changing + Making a Table VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a couple of lines bigger then the rest. I have an overall size enabled... but I was wondering if there is a specific way you can make just ONE line bigger? Its probably something simple that I am just missing.

I have provided all code relevant to my printing process. The one piece that I would like to make bigger has a comment above it...

Also, in the prices sections (also has a comment) is there anyway to make a pretty table? Or space everything out all nice and neat?

Thanks!

```
    Private lines As New List(Of String)
Private loopCount As Integer
Private WithEvents docToPrint As New Printing.PrintDocument

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    lines.Clear()
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Date:" & DateTimePicker1.Value)
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Company Information: ")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Company Name: " & txtCustName.Text)
    lines.Add("Part Name: " & txtPartName.Text)
    lines.Add("Qty per Year: " & yearQty.ToString)
    lines.Add("Qty per Batch/Shipment: " & batchQty.ToString)
    lines.Add("Equipment Used Information: ")
    lines.Add("Vib Machine Used: " & lblVMachineName.Text)
    lines.Add("Vibratory Media Used: " & lblVibMedia.Text)
    lines.Add("Liquid Compound Name: " & lblCompname.Text)
    'prices section that I want to look pretty (:
    lines.Add("Labor Cost Per Run: " & laborCostpRun.ToString("C2") & "        Per Peice: " & laborCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "          Per Year: " & laborcostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Media Cost Per Run: " & mediaCostpRun.ToString("C2") & "        Per Peice: " & mediaCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "          Per Year: " & mediaCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Machine Cost per Run: " & machineCostpRun.ToString("C2") & "    Per Peice:: " & machineCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "         Per Year: " & machineCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Compound Cost per Run: " & compoundPricepRun.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & compCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "       Per Year: " & compCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Factory Overhead per Run: " & factOH.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & facOHpPc.ToString("C2") & "    Per Year: " & facOHpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Total Process Cost per Run: " & processCost.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & processCostpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & processCostpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Business Overhead per Run: " & bOH.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & bOHpPC.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & boOHpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Sales Commision per Run: " & salesComm.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & salesCommpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & salesCommpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Profit per Run: " & profit.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & profitpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & profitpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Total Price per Run: " & grandTotalpRun.ToString("C2") & "Per Peice: " & grandTotalpPc.ToString("C2") & "   Per Year: " & grandTotalpYr.ToString("C2"))
    lines.Add("Runs per Week: " & runspWeek.ToString)
    lines.Add("Runs per Year: " & runspYear.ToString)
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    'make this bigger, like title size
    lines.Add("Parameters as of April 2015:")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("As for media, the following costs are implemented:")
    lines.Add("HD-1 Cone: Price: $1.47/lb ; Density/lb: 100 ; Wear Rate: .5")
    lines.Add("F 3/16 Cyl.: Price: $1.54/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("ECH 7/8 T2: Price: $1.14/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: .3")
    lines.Add("ECH 7/16 Cyl: Price: $1.10/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: .3")
    lines.Add("3/16 Steel Ball Cone: Price: $3.50/lb ; Density/lb: 270 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("UFX 3/8X3/8 ACT: Price: $.86/lb ; Density/lb: 100 ; Wear Rate: 1")
    lines.Add("XC 7/8 Cyl.: Price: $1.10/lb ; Density/lb: 95 ; Wear Rate: .35")
    lines.Add("LD-2 3/4 Cone: Price: $1.40/lb ; Density/lb: 70 ; Wear Rate: .2")
    lines.Add("HD-1 Tri-Star 1-3/8 X 1/2: Price: $1.47/lb ; Density/lb: 100 ; Wear Rate: .5")
    lines.Add("5/16 Steel Ball Cone: Price: $2.75/lb ; Density/lb: 270 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("25/32 Steel Cone: Price: $3.25/lb ; Density/lb: 270 ; Wear Rate: 0")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("As for machines, the following costs are implemented: ")
    lines.Add("Torex TG-299F: $2/hr")
    lines.Add("Sweco 1.2: $2/hr")
    lines.Add("Torex 6026A: $9/hr")
    lines.Add("Torex 6026B: $9/hr")
    lines.Add("Sweco FM10: $5/hr")
    lines.Add("Sweco FM7: $5/hr")
    lines.Add("VT-5524 F: $11/hr")
    lines.Add("VT-5524 F: $11/hr")
    lines.Add("VTHT-2450: $9/hr")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("As for compounds, the following costs are implemented:")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 211: $3.96/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 551: $4.02/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 553: $6.90/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 4677: $5.48/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 842: $3.74/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 320: $3.42/gal")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 103: $ .89/lb")
    lines.Add("Rodeco 307: $ .79/lb")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Business Overhead Includes:")
    lines.Add("Office phone, officer salary, bank, dues + subscribitions, employee gifts, rent, accounting, outside maint.,")
    lines.Add(" utilities, office wages. For 2014 this was $463,000.")
    lines.Add("Since 2014 Job Shop Sales was 4% of total sales. 463,000 * 4% = $18,500. ")
    lines.Add("Divided by 4000 direct labor hours, equals 4.65/hr direct labor costs.")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("Factory Overhead Includes: ")
    lines.Add("Item:        Total 2014 Rodeco:      Vib Job Shop        Equip Cost")
    lines.Add("Repair:              $ 27                    $  7                  $ 20")
    lines.Add("Shop Supplies        $ 22                    $ 22                      ")
    lines.Add("Supervisor Labor     $ 50                    $ 20                      ")
    lines.Add("Shop Office          $  2                    $  2                      ")
    lines.Add("Rent                 $167                    $ 24                      ")
    lines.Add("Elect                $ 32                    $  5                  $ 20")
    lines.Add("Business Ins.                                $ 27                  $  3")
    lines.Add("Computer                                     $ 22                  $  3")
    lines.Add("Outside                                      $  2                      ")
    lines.Add("Wastewater                                   $  2                  $  2")
    lines.Add("Deprecition          $ 81                    $ 5                   $ 12")
    lines.Add("                                 $95,000/4000(labor hrs)=       52000/54.45(indirect hrs)    ")
    lines.Add("                                       $23.75/hr            $9.50/hr")
    lines.Add("Sales Commision = Sales x 35% x 6% ")
    lines.Add("Profit is 35%")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    lines.Add("")
    docToPrint.Print()

    Dim printer As New myPrinter

End Sub
Private Sub document_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True
    PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = True
    PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint
    Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        docToPrint.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub document_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) _
       Handles docToPrint.PrintPage
    Dim printFont As New System.Drawing.Font _
        ("Arial", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim row As Integer = 5
    For i = loopCount To lines.Count - 1
        If Not row >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom - 20 Then
            loopCount = i
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lines(i), printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, row)
            row += 20
        Else
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lines.ToString(), printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 10)
End Sub
```

Comment: You are specifying the font when you call the `DrawString` method.  If you want a different font, just pass it a different font.  I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: If you want a table you need to draw some rectangles and draw text to them. That last line your printing - `e.Graphics.DrawString(lines.ToString()` is just printing the name of the object not any of the data it holds - why do you want that?

Comment: Steven, every time I pass a new font in, it changes all font. Like it takes the rest of the page to say size 14 vs making the title 14 and the rest 12.

Comment: OneFineDay, sorry. That was left over from something else. I tried doing stringbuilder previously and that was just in there. It has been removed. I will look up how to draw a table on MSDN. Thanks.

Comment: @PaigeLee right... so don't pass it the same font for every line.  Pass it a different font only when calling `DrawString` on the lines that you want to be a different font.

Comment: Okay... so I have been working on this and getting nothing but errors every stinkin time. What is an example of how to edit one line of code? Without changing the others? Because what I am doing is apparently just not working.